# Solving a functional equation using Mobius transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations, mobius-transformation

[image]

I've done part (i) pretty easily but I've no idea about (ii). I think I want to use the earlier hint about the generators but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The functional equation with $z = x$ is $$f\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x}\right) = \dfrac{x}{x-1}.$$

The function equation with $z = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ is $$f\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x}\right)+f\left(x\right) = \dfrac{1}{x}.$$

The function equation with $z = \dfrac{x-1}{x}$ is $$f\left(x\right)+f\left(\dfrac{1}{1-x}\right) = 1-x.$$

Can you solve this system of equations for $f(x)$?

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you explain why from only one equation $f(1/(1-x)) + f((x-1)/x) = x/(x-1)$ we get $2 f(1/(1-x)) = x/(x-1)+1-x-1/x$ ? it looks quite magical at first.

Comment: Start with the equation $f(1/(1-z)) + f((z-1)/z) = z/(z-1)$. This holds for all $z \neq 0,1$, so it should hold for $z = 1/(1-x)$ where $x \neq 0,1$. By substituting $z = 1/(1-x)$ and simplifying, we get $f((x-1)/x) + f(x) = 1/x$. Similarly, by substituting $z = (x-1)/x$ and simplifying, we get $f(x)+f(1/(1-x)) = 1-x$. Note these substitutions are motivated by part (i) of the question.

Comment: I understood that (I gave the solution) but how from the group perspective can you explain that there exists such a substitution which will solve for $f$ that only one equation $f(a(x)) + f(b(x)) = c(x)$ ?

Comment: In the group from part (i), the group is over the set $\{e,g,h,gh,h^2,gh^2\}$ where $e(z) = z$, $g(z) = 1/z$, and $h(z) = 1/(1-z)$. It is easy to see that $h$ has order $3$, i.e. $h^3 = e$ but $h \neq e$ and $h^2 \neq e$. So from the given equation $f \circ h + f \circ h^2 = gh^2$, we have $(f \circ h + f \circ h^2) \circ h = gh^2 \circ h$, i.e. $f \circ h^2 + f = g$. By composing both sides with $h$ again, we get $(f \circ h^2 + f) \circ h = g \circ h$, i.e. $f + f \circ h = gh$. That's the deep reason why we get $3$ equations from just $1$.

Comment: we start from an equation for unknown $f$ : $$f + f h = a$$ in a ring where $h$ is inversible and of odd order $2N+1$. thus $\sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^k (h^k+h^{k+1}) = h^0 + h^{2N+1} = 2$ so that finally :
$$f = \frac{a}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2N} (-1)^k h^k$$

Comment: finally, we simply started from $f(1+h) = a$ and $1+h$ was an inversible element of the ring.